# Linq to Entities and SQL Server 2008 FileStream

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-entities, filestream, out-of-memory

**Backend:** SQL Server 2008 database with FileStream enabled

**Data Access:** Linq to Entities

I have thousands of pdf's that currently reside on a file server. I would like to move these pdf's off of the file server and into a SQL Server 2008 database so that I can manage them easier.

As a proof of concept (ie - to ensure that the new FileStream ability in SQL Server 2008 is what I'm looking for), I wrote a small app that would read and write these pdf's to the FileStream enabled database via the entities framework.

The app is very simple; here's the code:

```
datReport report = new datReport();
report.ReportName = "ANL-7411-Rev-Supp-1.pdf";
report.RowGuid = Guid.NewGuid();

// The following line blows up on really big pdf's (350+ mb's)
report.ReportData = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\TestSavePDF\ANL-7411-Rev-Supp-1.pdf");

using (NewNNAFTAEntities ctx = new NewNNAFTAEntities()) {
   ctx.AddTodatReport(report);
   ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

I have the line of code commented above where the error occurs. The exact error is 'System.outofmemoryexception', which leaves me with little doubt that the file size is what is causing the problem. The above code does work on smaller pdf's. I don't know where the exact limit is as far as file size, but my biggest pdf's are over 350 megabytes and they get the error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not using the **streaming** in FILESTREAM very much in your example....

Check out the [MSDN docs on FILESTREAM in ADO.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716724.aspx) and [this article](http://www.aghausman.net/dotnet/saving-and-retrieving-file-using-filestream-sql-server-2008.html) that both show how to use the SqlFileStream as a stream from C# - that should work a lot better (I would believe) than sucking the whole PDF into memory....

Marc

Comment: Thank you! I'd actually a decent chunk of the article on MSDN, but I must have missed the part about SqlFileStream.